# Opening Jupyterhub url on kubernetes is so slow(gets js, icon)

Tags: kubernetes, jupyterhub

I deployed jupyterhub on kubernetes using helm.
[image]

and I can login with ID 'admin'
but when I first login, the url doesn't respond or respond after 30~50 seconds later, it seems it fails to get the javascript file or icon.
When I refresh it, it works then.

[image]

Is there any problem with the network in my kubernetes cluster?

I'm using GlusterFS Storage Class for Dynamic Provisioning.

This is my config file when install jupyterhub using helm.

```
proxy:
  secretToken: "34999170ac41826f956ee1a757b53ff91ce6efabc3dfe24fcee863955efcc6b9"
```

The pod's log is like this(with user qqqqq)

```
[I 2020-12-23 05:22:21.664 SingleUserNotebookApp extension:158] JupyterLab extension loaded from /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2020-12-23 05:22:21.665 SingleUserNotebookApp extension:159] JupyterLab application directory is /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab
[I 2020-12-23 05:22:22.015 SingleUserNotebookApp singleuser:561] Starting jupyterhub-singleuser server version 1.1.0
[I 2020-12-23 05:22:22.022 SingleUserNotebookApp notebookapp:1924] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jovyan
[I 2020-12-23 05:22:22.022 SingleUserNotebookApp notebookapp:1924] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 2020-12-23 05:22:22.022 SingleUserNotebookApp notebookapp:1924] http://jupyter-qqqqq:8888/user/qqqqq/
[I 2020-12-23 05:22:22.022 SingleUserNotebookApp notebookapp:1925] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[I 2020-12-23 05:22:22.038 SingleUserNotebookApp singleuser:542] Updating Hub with activity every 300 seconds
[I 2020-12-23 05:22:25.096 SingleUserNotebookApp log:174] 302 GET /user/qqqqq/ -> /user/qqqqq/tree? (@10.233.79.154) 0.93ms
[I 2020-12-23 05:22:25.165 SingleUserNotebookApp log:174] 302 GET /user/qqqqq/ -> /user/qqqqq/tree? (@10.233.93.0) 0.76ms
[I 2020-12-23 05:22:25.185 SingleUserNotebookApp log:174] 302 GET /user/qqqqq/tree? -> /hub/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=jupyterhub-user-qqqqq&redirect_uri=%2Fuser%2Fqqqqq%2Foauth_callback&response_type=code&state=[secret] (@10.233.93.0) 2.31ms
[I 2020-12-23 05:22:25.561 SingleUserNotebookApp auth:981] Logged-in user {'kind': 'user', 'name': 'qqqqq', 'admin': False, 'groups': [], 'server': '/user/qqqqq/', 'pending': None, 'created': '2020-12-23T05:22:16.257525Z', 'last_activity': '2020-12-23T05:22:25.524384Z', 'servers': None}
[I 2020-12-23 05:22:25.562 SingleUserNotebookApp log:174] 302 GET /user/qqqqq/oauth_callback?code=[secret]&state=[secret] -> /user/qqqqq/tree? (@10.233.93.0) 250.52ms
[I 2020-12-23 05:22:25.654 SingleUserNotebookApp log:174] 200 GET /user/qqqqq/tree? (qqqqq@10.233.93.0) 71.92ms
```

GET //usr/qqqqq/tree? I'm getting stuck in here.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: May be k8s is pulling some image first time. Check pod events at the end of output from `kubectl describe pod_id container_name` command

Comment: When I create jupyterhub using helm, I have a pod 'hub-5b8f6fb56-dcbhs' and the last event is 'Started container hub'
But, when I enter the jupyterhub login page, I have to refresh.. Does hub's persistent volume can be a problem?(maybe k8s and GlusterFS with network?)
 it's made with GlusterFS and Heketi

Comment: That  is possible. We need to check logs/events of those pods.

Comment: I uploaded the log files above. I think I got stuck in GET /usr/jupyterhub_id/tree?.

By the way, Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

try looking for events of hub pod and also for user pods, it must be either taking time in allocating pvc, pulling image (for first time only if not present in machine) or setting up route in jhub. Also check whether you've added any postHook in user images config.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but, after I changed kubernetes version from 1.16 to 1.17, it works fine.